# How to make file changes start from the next cell

Tags: python, arrays, csv

Look, I have a file with headers on the first row: **["Date of creation", "ID", "Note"]**
And I have a function that changes a specific line,
but the changes occur from the first point, that is, from the date.
The date must be changed to the current one, not manually

```
def editNote(path):
    myList = []
    print("Please enter the new details for each of the following: ")
    # Create an empty array, write all the data from the file there
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            myList.append(row)
        file.close()

    # We display all notes by numbering, the user enters the number of the desired line
    print("Please see the details to editing: ")
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        print("Row" + str(i) + " :" + str(myList[i]))

    userInputToEdit = int(input("Which row would you like to change? Enter 1 - " + str(len(myList) - 1) + ": "))

    # Changing data on a specific line
    for i in range(len(myList[0])):
        newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(myList[0][i + 1]) + ": ")
        myList[userInputToEdit][i] = newDetails

    # Show modified ARRAY
    print("Please see the details of the new file below: ")
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        print("Row" + str(i) + " :" + str(myList[i]))

    # If yes, then we make changes already in the file
    changeCSV = input("Would you like to make the changes to the csv file? Y/N: ").lower()
    if changeCSV == "y":
        with open(path, 'w+', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            for i in range(len(myList)):
                writer.writerow(myList[i])
            file.close()
```

I tried to increase the i variable by one, but in the end I get the *list index out of range* error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python `range` function can accept two arguments `range(start, end)`, in which the first one is the start, so just start from 1 instead of 0.

```py
# Changing data on a specific line
    myList[userInputToEdit][0] = datetime.now()  # set date first
    for i in range(1, len(myList[0])):
        newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(myList[0][i]) + ": ")
        myList[userInputToEdit][i] = newDetails
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the date to the current date you can do the following:

change this:

```
# Changing data on a specific line
for i in range(len(myList[0])):
    newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(myList[0][i + 1]) + ": ")
    myList[userInputToEdit][i] = newDetails
```

to this:

```
    import datetime
    myList[0]['Date of creation'] = datetime.date.today()
    for i in range(1, len(myList[0])):
    newDetails = input("Enter new data for " + str(myList[0][i]) + ": ")
    myList[userInputToEdit][i] = newDetails
```

Important notes are:

Remember that each row is a dict so you access it by name, not index.

You can `import datetime` in the beginning

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).